# Count characters and spaces in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm currently writing my thesis in Latex. When handing it in I have to state the number of characters including spaces. It's is only the text itself I have to count and not all of my code for figures, tables etc. that are also in my latex document. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might have been asked before here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/how-to-count-all-characters-including-spaces maybe the answers will help you